# Create List / Library with Different URL and Title

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to create a document library with a different URL and Title in one operation, as opposed to creating then updating the title.

```
{ 
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' },
  'AllowContentTypes': true,
  'BaseTemplate': 101,
  'ContentTypesEnabled': true,
  'Title': 'Foo',
  'OnQuickLaunch': true,
  'RootFolder': { 'Name': 'Bar' }
}
```

I tried this but the /_api/web/lists endpoint ignores the RootFolder element. Is there any guidance on how to achieve this in one call?

Answer (score 0):

RootFolder is only a "Get" property so it can't be set. You really need to POST a second call to change the list title.